# Intersecting multidimensional keys

Tags: php, multidimensional-array

Say I have two arrays:

**`$array1`**

```
Array
(
    [app] => Array
        (
            [name] => PunchClock
            [shifts] => Array
                (
                    [maxhours] => 16
                    [minhours] => 4
                )

            [con] => Array
                (
                    [moog] => 3
                )

        )

)
```

and **`$array2`**

```
Array
(
    [app] => Array
        (
            [name] => 
        )

)
```

I'm trying to find a way use the second array in order to get its corresponding value coming from the first array. For example, if I were to call:

```
$value = $array2['app']['name']
```

The corresponding value would be PunchClock. If I were to choose `$array2['app']['shifts']`, the corresponding value would return an array containing `maxhours` and `minhours`. I've tried intersecting the arrays but not getting anywhere. I've running this in recursion but it's getting quite messy. I don't know what other options to use at this point. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Why don't you just do `$array1['app']['name']` then? It already gives you the data you want.

Comment: The second array is the array that was input as a string: e.g. "app.name" passed as a parameter. The function converts this into an equivalent array: $array['app']['name']. I want it to search through the original data and return only the portion of the array that's being asked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function array_intersect_keys_recursive($a, $b)
{
    $r = array();
    foreach ($a as $k => $v)
    {
        if (is_array($a[$k]) && isset($b[$k]) && is_array($b[$k]))
        {
            $r[$k] = array_intersect_keys_recursive($a[$k], $b[$k]);
            continue;
        }
        if (isset($a[$k]) && isset($b[$k]))
        {
            $r[$k] = $a[$k];
        }
    }
    return $r;
}

$a = Array
(
    'app' => Array
        (
            'name' => 'PunchClock',
            'shifts' => Array
                (
                    'maxhours' => 16,
                    'minhours' => 4
                ),

            'con' => Array
                (
                    'moog' => 3
                )

        )

);

$b = Array
(
    'app' => Array
        (
            'name' => ''
        )
);


$c = array_intersect_keys_recursive($a, $b);

print_r($c);
```

The above example will output:

```
Array
(
    [app] => Array
        (
            [name] => PunchClock
        )

)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you need something like this?

```
function find($array1, $array2){
    foreach($array1 as $key => $value){
        if($value == null){
            return $array2[$key];
        } elseif(is_array($value)){
            return find($array2[$key], $value);
        } else {
            throw new Exception("value not found");
        }
    }
}
```

When you use it like this:

```
$array1 = array(
        'app'=> array(
                'name' => 'punchClock',
                'shifts' => array(
                        )
                )
        );

$array2 = array(
        'app'=> array(
                'name' => null
        )
);
echo find($array1,$array2);
```

it will print `punchClock`

Answer (score 0):

check the following code

```
$array1['app']['name'] = 'Punch Clock';
$array1['app']['shift'] = array("maxhours" => "16", "minhours", "4");
$array1['app']['con'] = 'Moog';


$array2['app']['shift'] = array("maxhours" => "16", "minhours", "4");
$result=array_intersect($array2,$array1);
```

### Output

```
Array
(
    [app] => Array
        (
            [shift] => Array
                (
                    [maxhours] => 16
                    [0] => minhours
                    [1] => 4
                )

        )

)
```